# Using Multiple Where Clauses in ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.4

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4, how can I pass `Where` clause and calculate  Field `L_STATE` based on Values on another field called `L_ST_CODE`.

What I have in 4 Unique values of `135, 138 , 148, 136`

```
if (L_ST_CODE == 135){
   L_STATE = "Item_1"
}
if (L_ST_CODE == 136){
   L_STATE = "Item_2"
}
if (L_ST_CODE == 138){
   L_STATE = "Item_3"
}
if (L_ST_CODE == 148){
   L_STATE = "Item_4"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use the Python Parser of the ArcGIS Field Calculator to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Field Calculator's python parser, and use a python dictionary.

In the Pre-logic script code:

```py
def l_state(stcode):
    stcodedict = {135: "Item_1", 136: "Item_2", 138: "Item_3", 148: "Item_4"}

    if stcode in stcodedict:
        x = stcodedict[stcode]
        return x
```

Expression:

```py
l_state(!L_ST_CODE!)
```

This checks if the value in `L_ST_CODE` is a key in the dictionary, and if it does then it sets the value in the field you are calculating to the value of the corresponding key.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to use the field calculator for this task, I would suggest you simply perform a "select by attribute"  statement, 1 for each L_ST_Code you show above.

Then after you select the first one (i.e. "L_ST_CODE" = 135), calculate the field and enter "item1".

This could of course be done using an update cursor with arcpy if you have a lot more values to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the multiple conditions *in steps*, and use the field calculator 4 times, one for each unique value.

For each `L_ST_CODE` value select and then calculate `L_STATE` for the selected records.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a look up table (nonspatial) that has the L_ST_CODE and the answer you want. You can do this by summarizing or copying existing  L_ST_CODE data, adding a field, and populating it with the L_STATE value.

Then join your original table using L_ST_CODE, then do your field calculation to copy your looked up value into L_STATE. This is what the first Python answer is doing. I just like using databases. If you will be doing this change again, a database table will document what changes are to be made.